# Mysql query to subtract sum of a column in a table from a value in another table with clauses

Tags: mysql

There are employees in a company, each employee gets his salary each month. The employee can borrow some amount of money from his salary many times during a month.

*It is required to display the employee name, his salary, the amount of money borrowed last time ,the sum of money borrowed and the remaining money from his salary at each transaction in a specific month.*

These are my tables structures:

```
    CREATE TABLE `employees`
    (
      `Employee_Id` Int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `Employeer_Name` Char(150) NOT NULL,
      `Job` Varchar(100),
       PRIMARY KEY (`Employee_Id`)
     ) ENGINE = InnoDB
      AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
      ROW_FORMAT = Compact;

    CREATE TABLE `Months`
    (
      `Month_Id` Int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `Month_Name` Varchar(100),
      PRIMARY KEY (`Month_Id`),
      UNIQUE `Month_Id` (`Month_Id`)
    );

    CREATE TABLE `Employees_Salary`
    (
      `Month_Id` Int NOT NULL,
      `Employee_Id` Int NOT NULL,
      `Salary` Decimal(10,2)
    );

    CREATE TABLE `salary_transaction`
    (
      `Salary_Transaction_Id` Int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `money_amount` Decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
      `salary_transaction_date` Date NOT NULL,
      `Month_Id` Int,
      `Employee_Id` Int,
      PRIMARY KEY (`Salary_Transaction_Id`)
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB
     AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
     ROW_FORMAT = Compact;
ALTER TABLE `Employees_Salary` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Month_Id`,`Employee_Id`);
    
ALTER TABLE `Employees_Salary` ADD CONSTRAINT `Relationship41` FOREIGN KEY (`Month_Id`) 
  REFERENCES `Months` (`Month_Id`) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
    
ALTER TABLE `Employees_Salary` ADD CONSTRAINT `Relationship42` FOREIGN KEY (`Employee_Id`) 
  REFERENCES `employees` (`Employee_Id`) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
    
ALTER TABLE `salary_transaction` ADD CONSTRAINT `Relationship43` FOREIGN KEY (`Month_Id`, `Employee_Id`) 
  REFERENCES `Employees_Salary` (`Month_Id`, `Employee_Id`) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I have tried this code ***but it subtract the last amount of money borrowed only from the salary***

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.employee_name, es.Month_Id, es.Salary, m.Month_Id, s.money_amount, 
    es.Salary-s.money_amount 
  FROM employees e 
  JOIN Employees_Salary es ON e.Employee_Id=es.Employee_Id 
  INNER JOIN Months m ON es.Month_Id=m.Month_Id 
  INNER JOIN salary_transaction s 
  WHERE es.Month_Id=1 AND es.Employee_Id=1 
 ORDER BY Salary_Transaction_Id DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

[All codes here in dbfiddle.uk site](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3668433e7e5920c660f78c88fd47cc08)

Comment: do want the result grouped by employee or transactions?

Comment: I think transactions because the employee is known

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you're missing `ON` after `INNER JOIN salary_transaction s`  and since you specifically looking for `WHERE es.Month_Id=1 AND es.Employee_Id=1` , I don't think `ORDER BY Salary_Transaction_Id DESC` and `LIMIT 1` are needed. For the time being, let's remove that. What you need is actually a `SUM()` of total being borrowed and a `GROUP BY`. Something like this:

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.employee_name, es.Month_Id, es.Salary, m.Month_Id,
       SUM(s.money_amount) AS "Total Borrowed", 
       es.Salary-SUM(s.money_amount) AS "Salary Balance"
  FROM employees e 
  JOIN Employees_Salary es ON e.Employee_Id=es.Employee_Id 
  INNER JOIN Months m ON es.Month_Id=m.Month_Id 
  INNER JOIN salary_transaction s ON e.Employee_Id=s.Employee_Id 
  WHERE es.Month_Id=1 AND es.Employee_Id=1 
  GROUP BY e.employee_id, e.employee_name, es.Month_Id, es.Salary, m.Month_Id;
```

Here's your updated fiddle : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3fbebdeccf3bc910339dd143e3bcf3c7